# Check if field generated error

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I can display errors for specific fields using this tag:

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="myField" />
```

But in addition to displaying the error message I would like to highlight the field in red. To do this I need to know if a field generated an error, and then add error class to this field.

How can I check if specific field has generated an error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Errors for fields are stored in `fieldErrors` map. So you can check for specific field error in `<s:if>` tag like that

```
<s:if test="fieldErrors.containsKey('fieldName')">
```